# Magento Checkout count weight of products which match attribute

Tags: magento, count, checkout

I need to count how many products of a specific type are in the checkout. But only(!) the products which are of a specific type. The type is defined in a drop down attribute.

This is a code counting the weight and works perfectly.
\template\checkout\cart.phtml

```
<?php $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;
}
echo $weight;
?>
```

But how to count only the products which have a specific attribute value?

Like 
=> "count only products which have Attribute color = green"

I found lot about collection and filter but it seems not to work for the shopping cart items.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the product model as you're looping ( Expensive ) and then you're able to call attributes on it like so:

```
foreach( $oItems as $oItem )
{
    $oProduct = $oItem->getProduct();
    $oProductModel = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $oProduct->getId() );
    // For code...
    $sColor   = $oProductModel->getData( 'color' );
    var_dump( $sColor );
    // For text...
    $sFormat  = $oProductModel->getAttributeText( 'color' );
    var_dump( $sFormat );
}
```

Comment: I combined your approach with the answer of @Hatef and than I got it running. thx

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the attribute value (after loading your product):

```
 $product = $item->getProduct();
 $value = $product->getAttributeText($yourAttributeCode);
```

But notice for this in order to work you need to set: *'Show in Product Listing'* or *'Used in Product Listing'* to yes in the attribute editor from admin panel.

---

And for the grouping part, one possible way could be doing something like this (it makes sense only if you have a small number of values for your specific attribute):

```
$weights = array ('redWeight' => 0, 'blueWeight' => 0, 'yellowWeight' => 0, ..);
$groupRed = array();
$groupGreen = array();
 ...

foreach($items as $item) {
  $product = $item->getProduct();
  $value = $product->getAttributeText('yourAttributeCode');
  $weight = ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty());
  if($value){ //Do all products have this attribute?
    Switch($value){
       case "red":
           $Weights['redWeight'] += $weight;
           $groupRed[] = $item;
           break;
       case "green":  
          ....
     }
  } else {
    continue;
   } 
}
 ....
  HERE YOU HAVE GROUPS OF YOUR ITEMS ACCORDING TO THEIR SPECIFIC ATTRIBUTE VALUES
```

Comment: I used the answer of @vladimir who descriebd how to load products and combined it with your approach. But I skipped the arrays. Than it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSt be aware of loading unnecessary models. Product model should be already loaded when you are looping through your items and you don't have to load it again. These heavy models (queries) can dramatically decrease the performance of your website in the future.